# Composer install / GitHub token & API rate limits

Tags: github, composer-php

I'm using `composer install` to deploy my Symfony projects. I recently got errors from GitHub rate limit. I then created a token and I'd like not to have it globally configured, but to store it into the config section of the `composer.json`, so it will be shared by everyone.

**EDIT**: Concretely in `composer.json`, I have

`"config": {
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "mygithubtokenhere"
    }
  }`

However, when I generate the `composer.lock` file, there is no trace of my token inside.

My question is: What will happen while executing `composer install`, that from my understanding is only reading `composer.lock` file?
Does `composer install` also read the `composer.json` to get the config data?
**EDIT**: Or, is it impossible to have config data runing `composer install`?

**EDIT:**
Just to be clear, I don't want `composer install` to generate the `.lock` from the `.json` (my `.lock` is already generated). I want `composer install` to read my  `.lock` already generated. But I don't know if/how it reads the config section, that is only present in the `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I delete the composer.json (but keep the composer.lock), `composer install` prints the following error:

*Composer could not find a composer.json file in /path/to/my/project
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section*

That actually answers my question : `composer install` does not only read composer.lock file, but also the composer.json. So, it gets the config data from there.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you: 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file
Composer install checks whether if composer.lock exists. If it exists, it takes the info from the composer.lock ,else it generates the composer.lock

Comment: Thank you, I've read it already. Actually my question was not enough clear : I dont want composer install to generate the .lock file from the .json. I want composer to use a .lock file already generated.

Comment: If the .lock file has already been generated, composer install will use it automatically. is there any other .lock file in the same directory? check this link, it explains you fully: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: No, the directory only owns one .lock file, that I generate locally before pushing it to my server. Everything is ok with composer install and .lock file. My problem is to get the GitHub token required to overpass the GitHub rate limits. I defined my GitHub token in composer.json, but it's not present in composer.lock. In .json I have "config": {
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "mygithubtokenhere"
    }
  } And I don't have it in composer.lock